# Are electron densities and electrostatic forces possibly responsible for gravity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity

The idea I had was that whilst electrons usually orbit within the Bohr radius of atoms there is a chance of them appearing significantly further away than that, meaning that if all the electrons in something like the earth were taken into account then we would be being surrounded by electrons. The electrostatic forces generated by the electrons surrounding us would repel the electrons of our bodies from all directions keeping us on the ground as well as keeping the moon in orbit around us and us in orbit around the sun. This might go some way to explaining the symmetry between Coulomb's law and Newton's law and the apparent weakness of gravity compared to the force of electrical repulsion could be explained by the fact that the electrons would be appearing for only very brief instances. Also I think lots of other things could be explained this way, such as through using QED to explain gravitational lensing, as well as phenomena such as the Lorentz force. Does anyone think this could be right? Thanks in advance for comments.

Also asking whether or not electrostatic forces and probability densities may be responsible for gravity, as secondary effect, isn't unreasonable nor is it particularly non-mainstream and certainly keeps within the limits of having a theory that employs well understood concepts in mainstream physics.

Comment: The [shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) says that, if we were in a spherically symmetric shell of charge as predicted by your theory, we would feel no force at all! Can you get around that?

Comment: Ok, that's cool, I think so. The total number or the total likelihood of finding an electron the further away from an object one moves diminishes inversely proportional to the square of the distance, just like gravity. So the aggregated probability density of the earth is symmetrical but it also diminishes in inverse proportion to distance squared, meaning there are more electrons holding us in place on the ground than pushing us away from it, or rather there are enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it cannot be so, for many reasons. One thing is, the amplitude of electron wave function in atom drops exponentially, which would make this effects vanishingly small, and would make any gravitation forces drop exponentially with distance.

Comment: the force of gravity does drop exponentially, it's inversely proportional to the square of the distance, the symmetry with the electron density is what made me think of it. The force doesn't need to be much in space because of Newton's first law.

Comment: "inversely proportional to the square of the distance" is NOT exponential.

Comment: sorry I should have checked that, i thought anything using exponents would exponential, damn my feeble mind

Comment: You said "which would make this effect vanishingly small", which is exactly why I said it. So that an electron density could account for gravity.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this because, even though you do not say in your profile, this is a proposal that would  have some logic from somebody very young who is just learning.

> The idea I had was that whilst electrons usually orbit within the Bohr radius of atoms there is a chance of them appearing significantly further away than that,

This is a quantum mechanical frame. *In the quantum mechanical frame*, even though a probability exists for an electron to be outside its orbital, this probability is so small as to be considered zero for macroscopic dimensions.

> meaning that if all the electrons in something like the earth were taken into account then we would be being surrounded by electrons.

There is a zero probability for this to happen. In addition the planetary system, the galaxy, etc will be contributing and if one had the patience and computer means to solve the quantum mechanical problem, the result would be the classical situation, of electrons being confined in atoms and molecules in the planetary and astral objects. Because of the zero probability.

> The electrostatic forces generated by the electrons surrounding us would repel the electrons of our bodies from all directions keeping us on the ground as well as keeping the moon in orbit around us and us in orbit around the sun.

Here you are assuming a classical framework, i.e. dimensions much larger than h_bar. In this framework one has not observed electrons at loose ends . Matter in bulk is neutral, no long range electrostatic forces exist between neutral objects.

So the error is in ignoring quantum mechanical probabilities, and in projecting a quantum mechanical possibility into the classical framework .

Comment: matter in bulk is usually negatively charged (-0.5 usually) due to the fact that electrons outnumber protons 2:1 in most forms of matter, stars would be the exception with a charge of about -0.85 or so due to their content of helium. As for the probability density objection even small particles of matter (classical particles) such as grains of sand there may be 10^19 atoms in a grain of sand, so yes the probabilities are tiny but the numbers are enormous, so I just put two and two together. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: "matter in bulk is usually negatively charged (-0.5 usually) due to the fact that electrons outnumber protons 2:1 in most forms of matter," Man, do you post from some alternative universe?

Comment: @SamCottle  as Nicolas comments this is a wrong statement. way wrong,  against solid  experimental evidence.

Comment: guys there six electrons in an oxygen atom, three protons, three neutrons, the charge meaning the charge of the atoms is -3, sorry I said -0.5 that was a mistake

Comment: @SamCottle  alternate universe is correct. There are 8 electrons, 8 protons and  Oxygen16 is stable with 8 neutrons.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen

Comment: Well that was embarrassing, just ignore that bit, my gravity theory still works in spite of it. Also this isn't non-mainstream physics, quantum gravity theorists have been slowly starting to come around to the idea that spacetime and any curvature therein may well not exist, check Euclidean quantum gravity

Comment: That was arrogant of me to say the least but I still think my idea works.